# Warning messages when using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, svm

I keep getting this when I run SVM python code:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 44
    "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 43
    DeprecationWarning)
DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. This module will be removed in 0.20.
```

What does this warning messages indicate?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you familiar with the term 'deprecation'? It means that the module is scheduled for eventual removal, and you should probably avoid using it when writing new code, while also updating old code to not rely on it. But it tends to happen over a long period of time so folks have plenty of opportunity to deal with it to avoid eventual breakage. I'm not sure what else might be unclear there, could you let us know more specifically what you don't understand in the message?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

the latest stable version of scikit-learn is 0.18
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/

The version you are using has deprecated these modules.

Alternatively use

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Look at this discussion 
https://github.com/rhiever/tpot/issues/284

and this comment:
https://github.com/rhiever/tpot/commit/84c5e26b447251088826737612ccf0817ef43db2

Comment: it is not the next version who deprecates the modules, the modules are already deprecated in the current (version 0.18). Deprecated means that the modules are no longer maintained, usually in favor of an alternative or better practice. In this case, the developers indicate that cross_validation will be removed in version 0.20.

Answer (score 0):

It means that scikit-learn's SVM module internally uses modules cross_validation and grid_search. Both of these will be replaced in version 0.20 by the module's model_selection equivalents. So, you don't need to worry, once you upgrade scikit-learn to its next version, you should not see the warnings anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when running python file from terminal. In the RuntimeError description, it was suggesting to install python app and use pythonw in place of python and I did exactly that. Luckily it worked for me.

> pythonw filename.py